# Android - Server requests working on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, http, connection, emulation

I am at a loss. My asynchronous server requests are working on the emulator but with my own Android device the following error message comes up:

> java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out.

Other apps and the internet are working on my android device during the tests. Even in my application, including Google Maps is working. Also the server response, because I test it with the emulator and there it works.

Do you have any ideas where the problem could be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do u print logs? what does your log looks like?

Comment: you will find my log on this link: [link] (http://codeupload.com/5716)

Answer (score 0):

Reset your internet connection.or restart your device.

Comment: Sometimes it happens with me.inside my application it displays socket exception but other apps runs well.but when i reset connection.it works for me.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work, same behaviour as before. Google Maps is working inside my app and my requests to my server not. It seems that they even didn't reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , i reviewed my manifest file and found that the

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

is missing, adding that fixed it for me.
the misleading thing is that the application should crash when it request a feature not declared in the manifest.xml but it doesn't, yet works on the emulator perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Check if your Wifi is on
2. Try turning off your mobile data

You will also need to add the following to the maifests.xml file:

1. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> </application>`